# approximately, how many web sites are developed in asp.net till-to-date?

Tags: asp.net

Note: of course, i know that we can't get the exact number; but atleast i need an approximate answer. anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

17345892039219 websites are currently developed in asp.net till date and still going on.

Please dont ask for source of this data.

Comment: 17345892039220 - just developed the next one

Comment: I believe the source of that number is here: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2008-05-08/

Comment: @Harsha - Couldn't resist answering this one. Anyway, the answer from zhaph looks more reasonable to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some numbers can be found from the [Netcraft Web Server Survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/), giving 56,637,980 websites running on IIS up to 5 November 2010 for "Top Servers Across All Domains".

To be fair, this is about the web server, so not all of them will be running sites that have been developed in ASP.NET - they could be static HTML, classic ASP (yes, still), PHP, JSP or more, but I think it's a fairly reasonable assumption that if you're going to run IIS you'll generally be running an ASP or ASP.NET site on it.